# Docker & Shorewall

Tags: shorewall, docker

I'm using [Shorewall](http://shorewall.net/) on my server as simple [standalone firewall](http://shorewall.net/standalone.htm) and would like to use [Docker](https://www.docker.io/) as well.

By using a Docker container and its *port redirection* docker sets up its own iptables rules/chains which will be killed if shorewall is restarted. So the container will become *unreachable*.

Does anyone managed to save/restore the docker rules upon a shorewall restart or does anyone have another workaround?

See also:

- [Shorewall Mailinglist with similar question](http://sourceforge.net/p/shorewall/mailman/shorewall-users/thread/528FA4FE.6020703@shorewall.net/)
- [GitHub Issue #2801 @ dotcloud/docker](https://github.com/dotcloud/docker/issues/2801)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The following configuration changes should ensure traffic flow between Docker and the Shorewall host. 
Tested on Shorewall 4.5.21.9 but should apply to most recent versions:

**/etc/shorewall/shorewall.conf**

Make sure IP forwarding is enabled (most config items are Yes/No, but this one is "On"):

```
IP_FORWARDING=On
```

**/etc/shorewall/masq**

Enable masquerading (NAT) for your private Docker network (if you use a different network, i.e. you launch docker with `--bip=#.#.#.#/#`, then change accordingly). Change `eth0` to any interface on the host machine with external connectivity:

```
#INTERFACE:DEST         SOURCE
eth0                    172.17.0.0/16
```

**/etc/shorewall/interfaces**

Add an interface entry so Shorewall knows which interface the `dock` zone relates to:

```
#ZONE           INTERFACE               OPTIONS
dock            docker0
```

**/etc/shorewall/zones**

Create a new zone; note, `docker` is too long and will cause an "invalid zone name" error.

```
#ZONE   INTERFACE
dock    ipv4
```

**/etc/shorewall/policy**

You probably want to allow Docker containers to talk to the host machine *and* the Internet, so this is a good starting point:

```
#SOURCE         DEST            POLICY
# ...(other policies)...
dock            all             ACCEPT
# ...(other policies, catch-all)...
```

You may also need a similar `ACCEPT` policy for traffic from `fw` to `dock`, if you didn't already open it up with `fw` to `all`.

You can tighten this up further in the **policy** or **rules** files as needed. For example, the above does not explicitly allow outside traffic to reach your Docker containers; check your other zones/policies/rules for that.

Comment: ```IP_FORWARDING=Yes``` and ```IP_FORWARDING=True``` work as well.  I have it on several production routers, but your answer is much clearer than mine.  Great work.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance--when I restart shorewall after adding the given rules, I get a warning that dock is an "EMPTY INTERFACE"... and indeed, reading the above, it's not clear to me how shorewall can infer the connection between the 172.17 addresses and the zone 'dock'. Am I missing something obvious about how shorewall works?

Comment: Sorry about that, I missed out a change in the interfaces file. I've edited the answer, see new section `/etc/shorewall/interfaces`.

Comment: Thank you. It's working well also with shorewall 5 (which is docker-aware), to have the host joining its containers.

Comment: the masq settings are very important, otherwise a docker-container will not be able to access a other container using a external IP - it will get blocked

Answer (score 7):

Since Docker introduced its network isolation feature, the other solutions mentioned here are no longer sufficient if you want to use custom networks. Shorewall 5.0.6 introduces [support for Docker](http://shorewall.net/Docker.html) including Docker networks. This:

- Allows shorewall and docker to be started/stopped/restarted in any order
- Avoids the need for maintaining an extension script

Answer (score 2):

Just figured it out on my box.  Make sure /etc/shorewall.conf has:

`IP_FORWARDING=Yes`

Docker relies on forwarding, and I spaced that 'puppet' sets it to 'No' on all my servers.

Update:  You probably also need to masquerade traffic coming from docker out your WAN interface.

Edit `/etc/shorewall/masq` and you'll need a line similar to:

`br0         172.17.0.0/12`

In this case, my WAN interface is actually br0 (a bridge), but yours will probably be something like eth0.  (Use `ifconfig` to see your interfaces and their IP addresses).  On my machine docker uses 172.17.0.0/24 which is an RFC1918 private address range.  This may differ on other systems, but you can see the range by using `ifconfig` once again to look for the interface `docker0`.

Answer (score 2):

You can ensure that the Docker ruleset survives a shorewall restart by creating extension scripts which save the `DOCKER` chain before the restart, and then restore it again afterwards.  I've just put up a post with an [example of how to do this](https://blog.discourse.org/2015/11/shorewalldocker-two-great-tastes-that-taste-great-together/), although I'm sure it's far from the only possible method.

Answer (score 0):

The docker service can be restarted without impacting the running containers, and can be run after a Shorewall restart to reload the docker specific rules. There will obviously be a short time where networking to the container(s) is disrupted.

This is true at least on my few Archlinux installs.

Answer (score 0):

The refresh action do not purgate the iptable so this if you just want to refresh rules or policies, you just may run refresh instead of restart :

```
sudo shorewall refresh
```

Obviously, the problem still remains if you really need to restart shorewall.
Then, you have to restart docker and re-up your containers.

Answer (score 0):

One possible option is to run Docker with --net=host option, to allow containerized application access host network without ip forwarding and NAT.